# Formatted output of the function domain in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to print the domain of a function in a readable way. However, for some functions the domain of definition is quite complex. For example, the periodic function tan(x) or tan(x + 10):

**Desired result for tan(x):**
`x ≠ π / 2 + π * n` or at least `Interval.open(-π / 2, π / 2)`

**Actual results for tan(x):**
`Complement(Reals, Union(ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + pi/2), Integers), ImageSet(Lambda(_n, 2*_n*pi + 3*pi/2), Integers)))`

**Code:**

```py
from sympy import tan, S
from sympy.calculus.util import continuous_domain

x = S('x')
function = tan(x)
print(continuous_domain(function, x, S.Reals))
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to format the output of interval (in this case, the domain of a function) for any function in Sympy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what environment you're working in but with a unicode enabled console `pprint` will display like this:

```
In [2]: pprint(continuous_domain(function, x, S.Reals))
    ⎛⎧        π │      ⎫   ⎧        3⋅π │      ⎫⎞
ℝ \ ⎜⎨2⋅n⋅π + ─ │ n ∊ ℤ⎬ ∪ ⎨2⋅n⋅π + ─── │ n ∊ ℤ⎬⎟
    ⎝⎩        2 │      ⎭   ⎩         2  │      ⎭⎠
```

What this output is showing is that the domain is the set of real numbers except for the points `pi/2 + 2 n pi` and `3 pi/2 + 2 n pi`. Ideally that would be simplified to `pi/2 + n pi` but that simplification is not yet implemented.

If you're using a Jupyter notebook then `display` is better or you can use `init_printing()` to set the default display mode. See here:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html